# Error : No coinciden los tipos VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy haciendo una macro que compara dos columnas al mismo tiempo para realizar una operación, la columna A es de tipo Entero y la columna C es de tipo Fecha, el problema es que al cerrar el ciclo me arroja el error de `<Se ha producido el error '13' en tiempo de ejecución: No coinciden los tipos>`. Cabe mencionar que hace toda la operación excepto al final. Agradezco mucho cualquier sugerencia.

Mi codigo es la siguiente:

```
Sub ChecarHorarioComida()
    'Declaracion de varaibles
    Dim valor1 As Integer
    Dim valor2 As Integer

    Dim fecha1 As Date
    Dim fecha2 As Date


    Dim Row As Long
    Dim contador As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Row = 1
    contador = 0

    While ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value <> ""
        valor1 = ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value
        valor2 = ws.Cells(Row + 1, 1).Value

        fecha1 = Format(ws.Cells(Row, 3).Value, "Short Date")
        fecha2 = Format(ws.Cells(Row + 1, 3).Value, "Short Date")

        If valor1 = valor2 And fecha1 = fecha2 Then
            contador = contador + 1

        Else
            Select Case contador
                Case 0
                    Range("A" & Row, "E" & Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 96, 96)
                Case 1
                    Range("A" & Row, "E" & Row).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 0)                   

            End Select
            contador = 0
        End If
        Row = Row + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta es mi solución por si alguien le pasa algo similar...

```
Sub ChecarHorarioComida()
On Error Resume Next 'Controlar error

'Declaracion de varaibles   
Dim valor1 As Integer
Dim valor2 As Integer
Dim fecha1 As Date
Dim fecha2 As Date
Dim Row As Long
Dim contador As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Row = 1
contador = 0

While ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value <> ""
    valor1 = ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value
    valor2 = ws.Cells(Row + 1, 1).Value

    fecha1 = Format(ws.Cells(Row, 3).Value, "Short Date")
    fecha2 = Format(ws.Cells(Row + 1, 3).Value, "Short Date")

    If valor1 = valor2 And fecha1 = fecha2 Then
        contador = contador + 1
    Else
        Select Case contador
            Case 0
                Range("A" & Row, "E" & Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 96, 96)
            Case 1
                Range("A" & Row, "E" & Row).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 0)
        End Select
        contador = 0
    End If
    Row = Row + 1
Wend
```

Comment: en 23 horas con 50 minutos y algunos segundos podras marcar tu respuesta con el check verde, así ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Gracias hermano :D

Comment: Como sugerencia, cualquier respuesta debería incluir una breve descripción de lo que el código que uno sugiere hace y por qué resuelve la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Es muy probable que el problema pase por como estás iterando. Recorres las filas hasta que el valor de la celda en `Row` sea distinto de `""` o sea esté vacía (`While ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value <> ""`) , el problema es que con la última fila que si tiene un valor estás haciendo está lógica:

```
fecha2 = Format(ws.Cells(Row + 1, 3).Value, "Short Date")
```

Es decir recuperas la celda de `Row + 1` que obviamente si `Row` apunta a la última fila `Row + 1` será vacía.  Por consiguiente tendrás un error al usar `Format`. Si profundizar en la lógica de tu algoritmo, o bien el ciclo lo haces así:

```
While ws.Cells(Row + 1, 1).Value <> "")
```

O controlas el error de la última fila mediante un `On error`.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido tu sugerencia!